# Terraform on Cloud Build with multiple commands

Tags: docker, terraform, google-cloud-build

I'm using Google Cloud Build to run Terraform.

My goal is to run this:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: hashicorp/terraform:1.0.0
    args:
      - "terraform workspace select staging || terraform workspace new staging"
```

However, this fails because the `ENTRYPOINT` for the docker image is `terraform`.

When using GitLab CI, I can override this by adding the following:

```yaml
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
```

However, on Cloud Build, the `entrypoint` config only accepts a single string. I've tried various approaches and have been unable to get it to work, as they result in `terraform not found` errors.

Does anyone know how I can override the entrypoint of the Terraform docker image when using Cloud Build so I can use syntax like `||` or `&&` with my Terraform commands?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this (just an example without a `workspace`):

```
  - name: 'hashicorp/terraform'
    entrypoint: 'sh'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
          terraform init \
            -backend-config=bucket="a-backet-for-the-state-file" \
            -backend-config=prefix="a-prefix-for-the-state-file" \
            || exit 1

          terraform apply -auto-approve \
            || exit 1
```

Such construction works for me.

Or do you mean that the question is about `||` bash command?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the entrypoint in Google Cloud Build by using the [`entrypoint` key](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config#entrypoint). The documentation provides the following example:

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  entrypoint: 'node'
  args: ['--version']
```

In your case you could use the following:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: hashicorp/terraform:1.0.0
    entrypoint: '/bin/sh'
    args:
      - "-c 'terraform workspace select staging || terraform workspace new staging'"
```

Comment: I did attempt this but it fails giving `/bin/sh: illegal option - `... I think it's not liking the `-c` part... I also tried adding `sh -c` to the beginning.