# GCP "omnipotent" Service Account to create multiple services through Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, service-accounts

I am running an application using some 4-5 services on GCP, I have done it mainly to learn some new skills (including GCP) and it is not a commercial application so I run it on free credits, create a new account, transfer the database and run it there. Rinse and repeat.

Lately, I have been trying to learn Terraform and as such I try to create and configurate my services (such as setting up an SQL database with the right configuration, creating a Cloud Run-service with env variables etc). In order to do so, I am constantly running into permission issues if I e.g. use the Compute Engine-service account (which works fine if everything is already created!).

How should I create an "omnipotent" service account that I can use as a SA for my terraform creation of my GCP environment from scratch. The SA does not in itself need to be created through Terraform (although that would be neat). All I want is a SA that I can create, download and reference the JSON, and create all my GCP services.

Is it possible?

Comment: Since you are learning GCP and Terraform, I recommend learning which IAM roles are required for each service that you are deploying. That practice will be very useful in the future to debug problems. Terraform can create a service account, assign roles, etc. However, use a practice project anytime you are working with a project's IAM permissions as you can easily lock yourself out of that project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this is possible.

The operations you need to perform:

- Create Service Account in GCP console
- Use IAM & Admin -> Service Accounts -> Create Service Account
- Name it whatever you like, e.g. "terraform"
- In "Grant this service account access to the project" select "Owner" basic role.
- When created, click this account on the list and open "keys" tab.
- Use "add key -> create new key"
- Download the json and voila, you can use it in terraforming.

Note that you can use this json filein two ways:

1. Directly in the code (provider `credentials` argument) - the code would look like this:

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = file(var.credentials) # var.credentials is a path to the JSON keys
  project     = var.project
  region      = var.region
}
```

2. or you can run terraform while having GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
   environment variable set to the path to this file.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know details of your context, scope, requirements and restrictions. So my personal experience only.

I use a Cloud Build service and it’s build in service account.

That service account should be granted relevant permissions (I.e. an `owner` role) in proper projects. That is a “precondition”.

Then, I create a `cloudbuild.yaml` file in which I initialise and apply a terraform job.

Note: the terraform state file is stored in a GCS bucket. So, that is to be prepared as well.

Here is an example of a part of the `cloudbuild.yaml` file: [Terraform and Cloud Build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68081335/6073141)