# Terraform on GCP - Impersonation not working (missing permission in generating access token)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-build, terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam

I'm trying to create a CI/CD pipeline from the Terraform scripts used in my organization. The pipeline works perfectly when executed locally (using an high privileged account), but they don't when executed remotely.

I think it's a permission issue, but I cannot spot where.

I created a SA for Terraform and I granted it these roles:

```
resource "google_organization_iam_member" "org_tf_folder_admin" {
  count  = var.folder_id != "" ? 0 : 1
  org_id = var.org_id
  role   = "roles/resourcemanager.folderAdmin"
  member = "serviceAccount:${module.terraform_project.terraform_sa_email}"
}

resource "google_organization_iam_member" "org_tf_project_creator" {
  count  = var.folder_id != "" ? 0 : 1
  org_id = var.org_id
  role   = "roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator"
  member = "serviceAccount:${module.terraform_project.terraform_sa_email}"
}
```

I can see the roles are currently applied to the account.

Now, in `versions.tf` I asked Terraform to impersonate the Service Account

```
provider "google" {
  impersonate_service_account = ${module.terraform_project.terraform_sa_email}
}

provider "google-beta" {
  impersonate_service_account = ${module.terraform_project.terraform_sa_email}
}
```

But I get a 403 error when I try, for example, to list the folders inside the organization, or to access a project inside the `var.folder_id` folder. This is true when executed locally and also inside CloudBuild, so I think it's a permission issue, rather than a SA issue (but of course I cannot be sure). Perhaps some inheritance?

This is the error I get:

```
│ Error: Error when reading or editing Folder Not Found : folders/XXXXXXXXXXXX: Get "https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v3/folders/XXXXXXXXXXXX?alt=json&prettyPrint=false": impersonate: status code 403: {
│   "error": {
│     "code": 403,
│     "message": "Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
│     "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
│     "details": [
│       {
│         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
│         "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
│         "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",
│         "metadata": {
│           "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"
│         }
│       }
│     ]
│   }
│ }
│
│
│   with google_folder.env,
│   on main.tf line 37, in resource "google_folder" "env":
│   37: resource "google_folder" "env" {
```

### Edit

The cloudbuild default service account *can* actually impersonate:

```
resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "cloudbuild_terraform_sa_impersonate_permissions" {
  service_account_id = var.terraform_sa_name
  role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"
  member             = "serviceAccount:${module.cloudbuild_project.project_number}@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

but as I said, since it doesn't work locally too (when I execute using my user identity), the issue should be elsewhere

Any idea?

### Edit 2

I added a block to explicitly create the accessToken, but nothing changed. I'm running out of options, I must admit

```
provider "google" {
  alias = "tokengen"
}

# get config of the client that runs
data "google_client_config" "default" {
  provider = google.tokengen
}

data "google_service_account_access_token" "sa" {
  provider               = google.tokengen
  target_service_account = local.tf_sa
  lifetime               = "600s"
  scopes = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  ]
}

/******************************************
  GA Provider configuration
 *****************************************/

provider "google" {
  access_token = data.google_service_account_access_token.sa.access_token
}
provider "google-beta" {
  access_token = data.google_service_account_access_token.sa.access_token
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your desire to deploy (from a local host I guess) under your personal account (simplification, quick tests), however there may be some reasons to deploy by using cloud build only, and never deploy under anybody's personal account. The main reason - by using the cloud build - it is guaranted the deployement of _same_ code base using the _same_ deployment configuration, indpendently of any local host or user variations and permissions... To be honest, I never deploy from my account. Never.

Comment: I undestand what you mean, and I agree. Executing locally it's only a temporary (initial) solution for debugging those impersonations/permissions issues (with no success, btw). In facts, atm and with the abovementioned scripts it won't work on either way - both locally and within the cloud build - and this is part of the problem i would say...

Comment: When a terraform script is executed within (by) the cloud build, it is only necessary to provide relevant IAM roles to that cloud build service account, and a job is executed by that service account. Suppose there exist a cloudbuild.yaml file which contains terraform commands, and can be submitted (in the simplest case) by a plain "gcloud builds submit ..." command - https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit An idea of what might be inside that couldbuild.yaml file - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68066035/terraform-on-cloud-build-with-multiple-commands/68081335#68081335

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 403 Permission denied error such as Permission `'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist) is due to the principalSet on the service account IAM binding not matching the principalSubject making the call`. This means the service account that you are impersonating does not have the appropriate permission to access the intended resource. This is a permission issue on the resources, instead of being an impersonation issue.

To create or access a Token you need to grant the permission to impersonation service account `iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken`and  [Service Account Token Creator role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-permissions#directly-impersonate) . Try adding above permissions and have a try .

Refer to this [service account impersonation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-overview#impersonation) and [Blog](https://medium.com/@tanujbolisetty/gcp-impersonate-service-accounts-36eaa247f87c) by Tanuj Bolisetty.

Comment: tnx allot, this seems to be the issue! the build account was not able to get the token for starting to impersonate, rather than not be able to effectively impersonating

Comment: @GabrieleB do u have an answer in terraform ?